# How to handle No Internet Connection: Yelp API & AFNetworking

Tags: ios, swift, error-handling, afnetworking

Right now I'm making a little app the integrates the Yelp API but it crashes every time I try to perform a search and there's no internet connection. Not really sure how to approach this because I've never really dealt with error handling before with APIs.

Comment: Post your code.  Usually you would display some type of alert/toast informing the user that the network call failed.

Answer (score 0):

There is a Reachability library you can use, whenever you wish to connect to internet. Check if the network is reachable and then only make a call .
Else do not.